# issues on error handler with nextcord package

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py, chatbot

I have this code here which it should handle the command error of a discord bot using the nextcord.py package. The problem is, everytime i step into those error it give me in output only the MissingRequiredArgument error and the else statement
I checked with the debug and the variable error doesn't have any problem, it takes the method of the class which it is error but the problem is that when it pass in the if statement it just ignore the isinstance()

```py
@load.error
async def load_error(ctx : commands.Context, error : commands.CommandError):
    """
    "Handle load errors
    :param ctx: context
    :param error: Errors(ExtensionNotFound, ExtensionAlreadyLoaded, NoEntryPoint, ExtensionFailed)
    :return: None
    """
    if isinstance(error, commands.ExtensionNotFound):
        message = "Message"
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        message = "message"
    elif isinstance(error, commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded):
        message = "Message"
    elif isinstance(error, commands.NoEntryPointError):
        message = "Message"
    elif isinstance(error, commands.ExtensionFailed):
        message = "message"
    else:
        message = "message"
    await ctx.send(message, delete_after=5)
    await ctx.message.delete(delay=5)
```

Comment: Try asking in the nextcord discord server

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved this, here is the new code

```
@load.error
async def load_error(ctx : commands.Context, error : commands.CommandError):
    """
    "Handle load errors
    :param ctx: context
    :param error: Errors(ExtensionNotFound, ExtensionAlreadyLoaded, NoEntryPoint, ExtensionFailed)
    :return: None
    """
    if isinstance(error.__cause__, commands.ExtensionNotFound):
        message = f"L'estensione {error.__cause__.name.strip('cogs.')} non può essere importata, hai inserito il nome giusto?"
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        message = "Devi inserire il nome del file da importare"
    elif isinstance(error.__cause__, commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded):
        message = f"L'estensione {error.__cause__.name.strip('cogs.')} è già stata caricata, non c'è bisogno di ricaricarla"
    elif isinstance(error.__cause__, commands.NoEntryPointError):
        message = f"Non ho trovato nessun setup nell'estensione {error.__cause__.name.strip('cogs.')}"
    elif isinstance(error.__cause__, commands.ExtensionFailed):
        message = f"C'è stato un errore nell'importare l'estenzione {error.__cause__.name.strip('cogs.')}"
    else:
        message = f"{error} C'è stato un errore durante l'esecuzione del comando"
    await ctx.send(message, delete_after=5)
    await ctx.message.delete(delay=5)
```

Basically i had to specify the **cause** method of error object to get the instance of the error
Also this seems that is not necessary on the MissingRequiredArgument error